# Google charts - Stacked Bar Chart. How to introduce different colours within each bar

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am creating a stacked bar chart using google api. Each bar will consist of 3 "slices" representing Negative, Neutral and Positive feedback we received.

my data and options code looks as follows:

```
 data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Category', 'Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive', ],
              ['icon', 10, 800, 5],
              ['colour', 5, 5, 5],
              ['copy', 5, 5, 5],
              ['navigation', 5, 5, 5]
            ]);
        };
   options = {
        isStacked: true,
        width: '100%',
        height: 400,
        hAxis: {title: 'Category', textStyle: {bold : true, fontSize: 24}, titleTextStyle: {color: 'White'}},
        vAxis: {title: 'Responses', textStyle: {bold : true, fontSize: 24}, titleTextStyle: {color: 'White'}},

        };
  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('categoryChart'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

I have been trying to address that by adding an array like this to options

```
colors:['red','blue', 'green'].
```

to options but that only picks the first colour (red) and applies it to whole bars (slices are just separated by gradient).

Any tips how to control the colours of each part of the bar chart?

Best,

Adam

Comment: Just to be clear - I want to edit colours of slices within each bar - the bottom one to be red, middle one - blue and top one - green

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>It's possible to change the color style like this :</strike>

```
data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Category', 'Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive', { role: 'style' }],
          ['icon', 10, 800, 5, '#b87333'],
          ['colour', 5, 5, 5, 'silver'],
          ['copy', 5, 5, 5, 'gold'],
          ['navigation', 5, 5, 5, 'color: #e5e4e2']
      ]);
```

**Update :**

The problem occur in this line :

```
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('categoryChart'));
```

You using `google.charts.Bar` instead of `google.visualization.ColumnChart`

Working example :

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['corechart', 'bar']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBarColors);

function drawBarColors() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Category', 'Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive'],
        ['icon', 10, 100, 5],
        ['colour', 5, 5, 5],
        ['copy', 5, 5, 5],
        ['navigation', 5, 5, 5]
    ]);

    var options = {
        isStacked: true,
        width: '100%',
        height: 400,
        colors: ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Category',
            textStyle: {
                bold: true,
                fontSize: 24
            },
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: 'White'
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Responses',
            textStyle: {
                bold: true,
                fontSize: 24
            },
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: 'White'
            }
        },

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"><div>
```

---

*Reference*

- [Google Chart Docs Gallery BarChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Material)

Comment: Tried that, does not work - the chart is still displayed in default blue gradients

Comment: + I want to edit colours of slices within each bar - the bottom one to be red, middle one - blue and top one - green